# How to remove special characters from a list of strings?

Tags: python, regex, encoding, special-characters, lis

I am reading a file and using a regex on the file content to perform some operations. While reading the file, I don't find any special characters in it but after using the regex on the file content and saving it to a list, there are special characters like \t and \xa0 before numbers.

Example file content:

```
Hydrochloric Acid to pHÂ 3.3-5.0        q.s.    q.s.    q.s.    pH-regulator    Ph Eur, NF
```

After applying regex becomes:

```
Hydrochloric Acid to pHÂ\xa03.3-5.0\tq.s.\tq.s.\tq.s.\tpH-regulator\tPh Eur, NF
```

How do I remove all these without individual string replacement techniques?

Code:

```
def extract(filename):
    file=open(filename)
    file=file.read()
    print(file)
    print("wefewwEF3RF3")
    result = []
    med = r"(?:{})".format("|".join(map(re.escape, medicines)))
    pattern = re.compile(r"^\s*" + med + r".*(?:\n[^\w\n]*\d*\.?\d+[^\w\n]*(?:\n.*){2})?", re.M|re.IGNORECASE)
    result = pattern.findall(file)
#    result.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    newresult = []
    for line in result:
        newresult.append((line.strip()))
    return newresult
```

The `newresult` list contains all these special characters which are not present in the original file.

Answer (score 1):

If you know *all these special characters* you can use `maketrans` and `translate` methods of str to replace them with spaces following way:

```
txt = 'Hydrochloric Acid to pHÂ\xa03.3-5.0\tq.s.\tq.s.\tq.s.\tpH-regulator\tPh Eur, NF'
t = ''.maketrans('\xa0\t','  ')
newtxt = txt.translate(t)
print(newtxt)
```

Output

```
Hydrochloric Acid to pHÂ 3.3-5.0 q.s. q.s. q.s. pH-regulator Ph Eur, NF
```

`maketrans` accept 2 or 3 arguments. It creates translation table, which then might be used in `translate` method and work as follows: every char from first argument of `maketrans` is replace with corresponding char from second argument of `maketrans` (thus they must have equal length) and every character present in third argument of maketrans is removed. In example above `\xa0` is replaced with space and `\t` is replaced with space.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hi,

Can you check your code under a different Python version? It seems to work without error on 3.8.0.

```
def extract(filename):
    file='Hydrochloric Acid to pHÂ 3.3-5.0        q.s.    q.s.    q.s.    pH-regulator    Ph Eur, NF'
    result = []
    med = r"(?:{})".format("|".join(map(re.escape, file)))
    pattern = re.compile(r"^\s*" + med + r".*(?:\n[^\w\n]*\d*\.?\d+[^\w\n]*(?:\n.*){2})?", re.M|re.IGNORECASE)
    result = pattern.findall(file)
    #result.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    newresult = []
    for line in result:
        newresult.append((line.strip()))
    print(file)
    print (newresult)
    return newresult
extract('test')
```